# How to get data with ajax from a query string from a route in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

Like my title says, I am trying to pull data from a route with a AJAX Request that holds json data ('/home/playback/json'). But this data won't exist unless a query is done But I am trying to incorporate this from my client side page(playback.ejs) but I can't connect a query to my route that is connected to my database. Any ideas or documentations I should try out?

**AJAX Request**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#search').on('submit', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/home/playback/json",
        contentType: "application/json",            
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },error: function () {
            alert('error');
        },
        type: "GET",
    });
});
});
```

**Route.js**

```
app.get('/home/playback', function (req, res) {
    res.render('playback.ejs');
});
app.get('/home/playback/json', function (req, res) {
    //database connection
    dbconnection.query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE FILE_NUM LIKE '%" + req.query.searchFileNumber + "%' LIMIT 5", function (err, rows, fields) { 
       if (err) throw err; //Show any errors
        var data = []; 
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            data.push(rows[i]);
        }        
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something, but wouldn't this work?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/home/playback/json?searchFileNumber=1",
    ....
```

Also: watch out for SQL injection vulnerabilities. Without proper user input sanitation anyone could drop your database.

Comment: Yup, that worked for me to get my data. But what if I wanted it to do it with a form? Like if I have a input and wanted to change the url in the $.ajax to a different query how would I go about doing that?

Oh yeah I was just getting familiar with using MySQL with node first and I was going to learn more about connection.escape() or pool.escape() methods for SQL  injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: You could get the value of the input field using `var searchFileNumber = $("#id-of-input-field").val();` and then append it to the url using `"http://localhost:8080/home/playback/json?searchFileNumber=" + searchFileNumber`